# OKD scaling on vsphere

Tags: scaling, okd

Besides the examples from https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/example_inventories.html#multi-masters-single-etcd-using-native-ha and HA practices about 3 masters on 3 different physical hosts, collocated with the etcd nodes, is there a rule of thumb for the ratio of master/etcd for a number of compute nodes (or vCPU) ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the release of version 4.1, the answer is here https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/installing/installing_vsphere/installing-vsphere.html